# What is a bit set "high"? Simple explanation

Tags: bit

I know a set bit is a 1 (as opposed to a 0), but I can't seem to find a quick, simple explanation of what a bit set high is (in a 32 bit integer).

Answer (score 0):

Bit **set** or bit set **high** means **1**.

Example: If i have 8 bit number 10101010.

Now i want to check 5th bit is set or set high there i will see 5th bit if it is 1 it means it is set or set high otherwise it is not set or set low same in the case of 32 bit.

Visit it for programmatically example too [LINK](https://www.includehelp.com/c/how-to-check-a-particular-bit-is-set-or-not-using-c-program.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**High**, **Set** and **1** are synonymous in binary computing.

**High** is just the term more likely to be used by someone dealing with the hardware implementation, and refers to a higher voltage (**low** being the complement) representing the bit.

E.g. from https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/binary/bin_1.html:

> Generally, a logic “1” represents a higher voltage, such as 5 volts,
>   which is commonly referred to as a HIGH value, while a logic “0”
>   represents a low voltage, such as 0 volts or ground, and is commonly
>   referred to as a LOW value. These two discrete voltage levels
>   representing the digital values of “1’s” (one’s) and “0’s” (zero’s)
>   are commonly called: BInary digiTS, and in digital and computational
>   circuits and applications they are normally referred to as binary
>   BITS.